# import cycle not allowed

Tags: go

Buenos dias, estoy depurando un sistema que esta realizado en kataras/iris el framework para Go , al correr en terminal mi go run main.go me aparece el siguiente error

```
import cycle not allowed
package main
        imports ./src/Controladores/ExpresionRegularControler
        imports ../../Modelos/ExpresionRegularModel
        imports ../../Modulos/General
        imports ../../Modelos/ExpresionRegularModel
```

¿que podria cambiar para que me reconociera las rutas y mis imports?

Comment: Necesitas compartir también el código, con el puro error es muy difícil saber

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es arrojado cuando estas importando el mismo archivo mas de una vez estas creando un ciclo de importación. Solo tienes que revisar donde se esta duplicando esta importación

> imports ../../Modelos/ExpresionRegularModel

Answer (score 0):

La importación se debe realizar siempre desde src.

Si mi código del paquete A lo quiero emplear en el paquete B los dos códigos deben estar en la carpeta src y en carpetas diferentes y para la importación se debe poner desde la carpeta src

ruta del fichero /src/codigoA/a.go con paquete A (package A) -->

```
import "/codigoA/A"
```

Espero que haya sido de ayuda